# error when updating glut.h

Tags: opengl, glut

I use an old version glut.h in my project and it doesn't support **GLUT_WHEEL_UP** so I update it with a new one.

Then I meet an error saying Cannot locate procedure entry point **_glutInitWithExit** on my exe(not glut32.dll).

the update date of the older header is 1998 ,the newer one is 2005, and the .lib and .dll are all 2008.

So how can I solve the problem?

I have checked the 2 headers and found some difference between the two headers:

older version:

```
extern void APIENTRY glutInit(int *argcp, char **argv);
```

newer version:

```
GLUTAPI void APIENTRY glutInit(int *argcp, char **argv);
```

and

```
# ifdef GLUT_BUILDING_LIB
#  define GLUTAPI __declspec(dllexport)
# else
#  ifdef _DLL
#   define GLUTAPI __declspec(dllimport)
#  else
#   define GLUTAPI extern
#  endif
# endif
```

I guess the program will be fine if the Macro **GLUTAPI** go to **extern**, but no idea about why it doesn't make it.

Answer (score 1):

Don't mindlessly replace header files. Most likely the linker definitions (the `.lib` and the `.def`) files is of the very same version as the header file, as the DLL which effortlessly explains your problem.

Let me guess: You've installed the DLL somewhere in `C:\Windows\…`, right? **Don't do this!**

Let me guess: You've installed the `.h` and `.lib` somewhere in your compiler installation directory, right? **Don't do this!**

You want to avoid the DLL hell. The easiest way is to place a local copy of the header, the linker definitions and the DLL into your projects source tree; something like `${YOUR_PROJECT}/extern/FreeGLUT/{src,include,lib}`. Then configure your compiler and linker to look for headers and the library also in there. The DLL should be installed alongside the .EXE in the same directory.